# How to update RSS Feed every 5 seconds in Python using Flask

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, rss, feedparser

I did a lot of research and nothing relevant worked. Basically I am trying to scrape RSS Feed and populate the data in a table format on a webpage created using Python Flask. I have scraped the data in a dictionary form. But it does not fetch the data in real-time (or every 5 seconds) on the webpage.

Here is the code for scraping RSS Feed using formfeed, rss_feed.py.

```
import feedparser
import time

def feed_data():

    RSSFeed = feedparser.parse("https://www.upwork.com/ab/feed/jobs/rss?sort=recency&paging=0%3B10&api_params=1&q=&securityToken=2c2762298fe1b719a51741dbacb7d4f5c1e42965918fbea8d2bf1185644c8ab2907f418fe6b1763d5fca3a9f0e7b34d2047f95b56d12e525bc4ba998ae63f0ff&userUid=424312217100599296&orgUid=424312217104793601")

    feed_dict = {}

    for i in range(len(RSSFeed.entries)):
        feed_list = []
        feed_list.append(RSSFeed.entries[i].title)
        feed_list.append(RSSFeed.entries[i].link)
        feed_list.append(RSSFeed.entries[i].summary)
        published = RSSFeed.entries[i].published
        feed_list.append(published[:len(published)-6])
        feed_dict[i] = feed_list

    return feed_dict


if __name__=='__main__':
    while True:
        feed_dict = feed_data()
        #print(feed_dict)
        #print("==============================")
        time.sleep(5)
```

Using the time.sleep() works on this script. But when I import it in the app.py, it fails to reload every 5 seconds. Here is the code to run the Flask app, app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import rss_feed

feed_dict = rss_feed.feed_data()

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('home.html', feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I tried using BackgroundScheduler from APScheduler as well. Nothing seems to be working. Formfeed's 'etag' and 'modified' not being recognized for some reason (is it deprecated?). I even tried using the 'refresh' attribute in the meta tag. But that of course only updates the Jinja2 template and not the code itself:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

I am really stuck on this.

Here is a link to the (half complete) app: https://rss-feed-scraper.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

I tried a bunch of things but this is what I found was the easiest solution to this problem:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import rss_feed

app = Flask(__name__)

feed_dict={}

def update_data(interval):
    Timer(interval, update_data, [interval]).start()
    global feed_dict
    feed_dict = rss_feed.feed_data()

update_data(5)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    #feed_dict = rss_feed.feed_data()
    #feed_dict=feed_data()
    #   time.sleep(5)
    return render_template('home.html', feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

A simple update_data() solved the whole problem, did not need any additional module, JavaScript, AJAX etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
feed_dict = rss_feed.feed_data()
```

is at module level.

When Python starts, it executes these lines and won't reload it until you restart your app.

If you are interested in this topic, please google for `runtime vs compile time python`.

That said, I'd suggest that you do the polling with a JavaScript function which polls the remote RSS feed every 5 seconds.

This would look something like

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you.. However, I have one doubt..I am new to Flask. How can I put the entire Python script inside the Javascript setInterval()?

Comment: You don't - instead you just point your JavaScript snippet to the Flask endpoint/route where you fetch the RSS data. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data

Comment: Hm, I just found this article https://css-tricks.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-rss-feeds-in-javascript/  you could fetch and parse the rss completely with JavaScript, and then render it in a Flask / Jinja template - so many options!